# Commit and Update with Git GUI

Tags: github

I have use of Git GUI in Ubuntu, and I have change my file in local and commit but my file in Git-hub no change!
why ?
description for me and description that change update and commit with GUI ?

Comment: This is off topic since it really isn't about Ubuntu but you need to PUSH your changes to the remote server if you want them there.  You should read the git book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing to push the commit to the remote repository.

I should recommend you to have a proper knowledge of Git before continuing.

One of the millions tutorials you can find on the net is [this one](http://pcottle.github.io/learnGitBranching/) which is very good in my opinion.

The documentation of Github will be useful for this case: https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git/